# Android: setOnLongClickListener() is unreliable

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android-view, android

I have added a long click listener using [`setOnLongClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener%28android.view.View.OnLongClickListener%29). Generally, the long click listener is called as expected. However, sometimes the long click will appear to be aborted (the view highlights, but then unhilights even though it is still being pressed). This appears to occur when other pieces of the view hiearchy are updating (a progress bar, a counter, an animation, etc).

Is there anything specific that is known to interrupt or abort the long click period?

Comment: I think you said it, the UI thread is a single thread, and can only be doing one thing at a time, if can either handle your long click or handle updating other view, can't do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been caused by a variable width `TextView` (`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`). The displayed text occasionally changed after the user began a long click but before the long click duration had elapsed, preventing the listener from being invoked. The changing width of the label triggers a layout pass which invalidates the long click.

We were able to solve the issue by ensuring that the view remained a fixed width across text changes.

Answer (score -1):

You can update your UI in a new runnable

> final Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
>       public void run() 
>       {
>          updateYourUIHere(); 
>       }
>   };

also your onLongClickListener won't crash

Comment: Aren't you only able to update the UI in Android in the UIThread? Most of the time I have this the other way around then what you suggest: I'm in another Thread and want to display a Toast, then I must use the `runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){ @Override public void run(){ // Display toast or update UI } });` And since the UIThread is still a single thread like @LuckyMe stated, it isn't possible to handle a LongClick and display/update an animation at the same time.